# How to set up and run the code for "stlink" zip file from github in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, zip, github, assembler

I am new at Ubuntu (20.04) and assembly programming. What I need to do is to set up the "stlink" stlink-1.6.1-1.x86_64.rpm file  and/or  Source code.zip file in this github  link for release version v1.6.1 ( zip files are at the bottom of the explanations): https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink/releases/tag/v1.6.1.

(Stlink is a helper program to communicate between the computer and the arm STM32F Discovery board.)

I have double click the zip files and it does not started any kind of set up, it just go into the main folder in the zip file. Can anyone help me settin up this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading and extracting the zip file, please consult the README. It says, in part:

> Linux

> We recommend to install `stlink-tools` from the package repository of
> the used distribution:
>
> - Ubuntu Linux: [(Link)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/stlink-tools)

I suggest that you open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install stlink-tools
```

You should be all set.

Comment: In the note it  recommends the links  below but  I have solved the problem by clicking on the .deb file. It wroked. It seems that I was trying to install the wrong files i.e. the .rpm and the .zip ones. 

"Note: As packages distributed via the Debian and Ubuntu repositories differ from our self-maintained deb-package, we recommend to use the latter instead (see link below). It provides the opportunity to handle and fix user-reported package issues directly within the project and is not redundant to any limitations deriving from external maintenance guidelines.
Ubuntu Linux: (Link)"

Answer (score 0):

A very fast and easy to install on linux is EBlink.
EBlink is using a more sophisticated algorithm and is the fastest gdb server (for stlink).

Stlink-org is no longer maintained so for newer devices you have to look for alternatives anyway.

https://github.com/EmBitz/EBlink

Comment: Could you please throw more insight?